# Why is a static library 10Mb, but an .ipa using it is only 4Mb?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a workspace that contains a static library and a project using the library, I'm then building the project (using Jenkins) to create an archive for ad-hoc distribution.

The resulting file size for the built library is reported as being 10.4Mb, yet .ipa is reported as being 4.2Mb.
How can the .ipa be so much smaller than the library, and yet the app runs when installed so  it must be containing the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the library contains symbols necessary to linking (as well as debugging symbols, possibly), while the ipa file has been already linked (thus it does not contains information for the linker) and stripped of debugging symbols.

On another account, the ipa file is just a zip file, so its content is also compressed.

Answer (score 1):

This have multiple reasons:

- Static libraries contains additional information required for linking (like methods names and so on).
- IPAs are compressed archives. Similar to ZIP just with another file ending.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm that apple uses to compress into .ipa is very good .
If your bundle doesn't contain too many images the percentage can be as low as 15% (from the uncompressed size on disk).

Comment: .ipa is .zip only for iphone, ipad . Because of that limitation the compression ratio is low because it doesn't have to support multiple architectures ( zip is cross platform). Yes you can unzip it but you still get the raw file that only works on ios (except images of course)